# Set file owner in Maven Assembly Plugin TAR archive

Tags: maven, tar, maven-assembly-plugin

By default the Maven Assembly Plugin seems to set the owner of files inside a TAR archive to the executing user.  How can the file owner be set to something else?

The Maven Assembly Plugin assembly descriptor [format](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) allows setting the file mode, but there does not seem to be any reference to setting the file owner or group.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we should use another plugin "exec-maven-plugin" to run the following command before install:

```
tar -zcvf  XXXX-conf.tar.gz XXXX-conf --owner=101 --group=102
```